# Wrap a pile of choices inside a table in Symfony/Twig

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I want to group many piles of checkboxes listed bellow the same Label in this fashion:

[The desired widget](http://blogs.worldbank.org/impactevaluations/files/impactevaluations/Evans%20-%20Likert%20item.JPG)

I have this code:

```
$builder->add('cleanliness', 'choice', array(
    'choices'   => array('Strongly disagree', 'Disagree', 'Neither agree nor disagree', 'Agree', 'Strongly agree'),
    'multiple'  => true,
    'expanded' => true
));
$builder->add('waitingTime', 'choice', array(
    'choices'   => array('Strongly disagree', 'Disagree', 'Neither agree nor disagree', 'Agree', 'Strongly agree'),
    'multiple'  => true,
    'expanded' => true
));
... And a bunch of other checkboxes piles
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the controller:

```
$answers = array('Strongly disagree', 'Disagree', 'Neither agree nor disagree', 'Agree', 'Strongly agree');

// ...

$builder->add('cleanliness', 'choice', array(
    'label' => 'The clinic is clean',
    'multiple' => true,
    'expanded' => true,
    'choices' => $answers
));
$builder->add('waitingTime', 'choice', array(
    'label' => 'My waiting time was reasonable',
    'multiple' => true,
    'expanded' => true,
    'choices' => $answers
));

// ...

return array('form' => $form->createView(), 'answers' => $answers);
```

Then in the view...

```
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <td></td>
  {% for answer in answers %}
    <td>{{ answer }}</td>
  {% endfor %}
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td>{{ form_label(form.waitingTime) }}</td>
  {% for choice in form.waitingTime %}
    <td>{{ form_widget(choice) }}</td>
  {% endfor %} 
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td>{{ form_label(form.cleanliness) }}</td>
  {% for choice in form.cleanliness %}
    <td>{{ form_widget(choice) }}</td>
  {% endfor %} 
  </tr>
  {# and so on... #}
</table>
```

Anyways, that's the general gist. Should those choices really be checkboxes though, or radio buttons so they can only select one of each? If so keep expanded set to true and multiple set to false.